# wordpress codex Increasing memory allocated to PHP - Questions

Tags: wordpress

after I obviously damaged my database by moving a wordpress site to another url I would like to try to get everything work again by using the "better search & replace plugin". The plugin works fine so far, but at one point I get a white screen. In the plugins FAQs it is mentioned that "This is likely an issue with your PHP memory limit. Try temporarily increasing it by defining the memory limit in your wp-config.php file as shown here" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/faq/). So I read the instructions on the codex site http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Increasing_memory_allocated_to_PHP under point "Increasing memory allocated to PHP" BUT there are some questions left to me. I hope to get some answers here?

This is what I´m not clear about:
- I don`t have to change anything in the wp-config.php right?
- I do have to go to wp-settings.php and add "define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M' );" -> but where do I have to put it in exactly???
- "When in the administration area, the memory can be increased or decreased from the WP_MEMORY_LIMIT by defining WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT." What does that mean??? What admin area is meant here? Where in the wordpress admin area can I make such definitons???
- "Please note, this has to be put before wp-settings.php inclusion. " -> does that mean I have to make the changings in the wp-settings.php and than upload the file to the webspace? BUT before I need to do what exaclty? What do they mean with this?

Would be so great if somebody could help me answering me these questions.

Thanks in advance
BR
Heidi

Answer (score 1):

The define line you mention has to go in the wp-config.php, I would considering increasing it to something like 128M. It has to be before the line where wp-config.php stands:

`/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`

The other line you mention is only effective when a script is used within the WordPress admin (/wp-admin/). "Normal" requests are not affected by WP_MAX_MEMORY_LIMIT. It can be next to the line above.

Do not edit the wp-settings.php file, you don't have to.

Comment: Hi Niels, thanks for your fast reply. So I don`t need the second one? I only have to put the code in the wp-config.php and upload it to webspace, correct?

Comment: @NielsvanRenselaar, what should I do so the changes take effect? It still doesn't show me the recommended memory on "System status" page. Thanks.

Comment: @DaniloRamirez if that is the case, then your hosting has disabled the manual manipulation of this variable and you should contact them.